# UIPopoverController Setting height when used with PresentFromBarButtonItem

Tags: cocoa-touch, uipopovercontroller

I have a UIPopoverController which displays a UItableview. I use the PresentFromBarButtonItem method.

How do I tell the UIPopoverCOntroller to be only 200px high? By default it is full screen height.

Comment: I found it> In the ViewDidLoad call this method: this.ContentSizeForViewInPopover = new SizeF (250, 210);

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the ViewDidLoad of the view you are displaying call this method:

`self.contentSizeForViewInPopover = CGSizeMake(250, 210);`